# PHP/Symfony: Create Application Context for Cron/Task

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4, connection-timeout, cron-task

I have a long operation that I can no longer run from the UI as it exceeds the maximum execution time as well as memory limit. I am fairly aware of how I can set tasks in a table, and have a cron execute a `sfTask` that finishes pending tasks.

Can someone let me know the following:

1. Which is the best PHP/Symfony plugins are to manage jobs/tasks? 
   I'm not using Zend and see that `sfTaskLoggerPlugin`, `sfGearmanPlugin` and `sfJobQueuePlugin` have not been recently updated.
2. How can I create a context and make app-config, settings, etc available to the task?
3. How can I add a parameter to the context that methods can read to identify if they have been called by the cron/task or HTTP request?

All inputs are appreciated.

PS: Have referred [Long script in admin, task in Symfony?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658003/long-script-in-admin-task-in-symfony) and few others :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think most of what you need is covered by the standard documentation.

http://www.symfony-project.org/cookbook/1_2/en/tasks

I use Symfony tasks frequently through scripts that hand-off through a cron job. I use environment switching via the command line, just like the docs discuss. I use parameter passing too.

Symfony tasks are very powerful, and give you everything that you need from the CLI in order to reach into your application and execute what you need.

If after reading the docs, you have a more specific question, post it, and we'll do our best to answer you.

Comment: thanks mate, I will try it out. Would there be a way to tell my function that it's running within a task? (as against a HTTP request)

Comment: Can I also set a current user in the context? to emulate that a task is being run for a user?

Comment: Yes to both. You could create your own environment for your tasks and query context to obtain the environment name and use that in your function. Of course you can pass it a parameter too. 

While you're in a task, you can have access to anything you want. You can pull the user object from sfGuardUser if you choose.

Comment: thanks. Im following your approach, but might need some help on the way. I was trying to signin a user via $context->getUser()->signIn($guard_user, true); but got an error: Notice: Undefined index: REMOTE_ADDR in symfapp\plugins\sfDoctrineGuardPlugin\lib\user\sfGuardSecurityUser.class.php on line 158 - probably where its trying to read from $Server or something. What is the way out to set user in context? should i set it through $context->factories['user']? would i be by-passing some logic?